# How to make an instrumentation test for a fragment that is using activityViewModels?

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, mockito, android-instrumentation

So my setup is that I initialize all the `viewModels` on MainActivity then use `activityViewModels` to the `Fragment`s that don't need their own instance of the `viewModels`. Then I wanted to create an instrumentation test for one of those `Fragment`s that don't have its own `viewModel` instance and I kept getting an error that the `viewModel` instance can't be created. Then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216441/10464730) and tried to copy it with just `Mockito`. The code I made is below.

```
val viewModel: SomeViewModel = mock(SomeViewModel::class.java)

val viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = mock()
Mockito.`when`(viewModelFactory.create(SomeViewModel::class.java)).thenReturn(viewModel)
```

Now, that code throws an error saying that `Mockito` can't mock SomeViewModel because it's a final class. I already tried that weird fix that needed a file with a specific "mock-maker-inline" content and it didn't work.

I can't find any very similar questions about mocking a `activityViewModels` out there so I created one. Do I need Mockk?